# geo_point for all indexs template mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a field "location" with "lat" and "lon" fields on all my logs. The logs indexs on elastic are different. Some of them goes to "logstash-YYY-MM-dd", others go to "exception-YYYY-MM-dd", and many others.
But I can't make all of them to mapp the location field as a geo_point. I'm aware of the *default* mapping and the dynamic mappings but I can't make it work. I don't undertand the documentation or find a clear example on the web. 
What I want is that elastic manages all "location" fields, from any log, and converts them to "geo_point" no matter the index or type or whatever. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with [index-template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html)

```
PUT /_template/template_name
{
  "order": 0,
  "template": "*",
  "settings": {},
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- This would apply geo_point type for all field with the name *location*.
- The *order* field is used for merging two or more templates.

> The order of the merging can be controlled using the order parameter, with lower order being applied first, and higher orders overriding them

---

**NOTE:**

> Templates are only applied at index creation time. Changing a template will have no impact on existing indices.

Comment: That's perfect. It works like a charm. Thank you so much.